# Calculate averages of rows in a data table using arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to calculate averages for both rows and columns. So, far I could get the average for columns, however, I have hard time calculating average for rows.

I have my data table like this,

```
Example1      Example2    Example2  
 85              75         92
 80              91         89
 85              52         78
```

So far What I am doing is taking them each column as an array like this:

```
int[] Example1 = {85, 80, 85};
int[] Example2 = {75, 91, 52};
int[] Example3 = {92, 89, 78};
```

And then I created a method like this (to calculate average for each column in the table),

```
public static void avg_calc(int[] examples) { 
    int sum = 0;
    int avg;
    for (int i = 0; i < examples.length; i ++) {
        sum += examples[i];
    }
    avg = sum/examples.length;
    System.out.println("Average is " + avg);
}
```

This way, when I do  `avg_calc(Example1)`, I can calculate average for 'Example1` array, which is 83.

However, I want to calculate the average of `Example1`, `Example2`, and `Example3` , for example, average for first row, which will be 84.

How can I add another array into my function to calculate the average for rows?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I add another array into my function to calculate the average
>   for rows?

One way to do it:

```
    int[] Example1 = {85, 80, 85};
    int[] Example2 = {75, 91, 52};
    int[] Example3 = {92, 89, 78};
    int[][] examples = {Example1, Example2, Example3}; // new array

    for (int i = 0; i < examples[0].length; i++) {
        double rowAverage = 0;
        for (int[] arr : examples) {
                rowAverage += arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Average of row " + (i + 1) + ": " + rowAverage / examples.length);
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Average of row 1: 84.0
Average of row 2: 86.66666666666667
Average of row 3: 71.66666666666667
```

Comment: Great, I added `int[][] Examples` into my method and created iterated through the Examples as you have. When I pass `avg_calc(Example1, Examples)` I get the row average repeated under each column's average. I think I have to modify my print statements.

Comment: I actually prefer @Paul Lemarchand's answer: this way you write a method that calculates an average for a row (index) - and call it the number of times you need it. It ends up more modular IMO.

Answer (score 2):

@alfasin 's answer is great, here is a java 8 solution :

```
public static int getRowAverage(int index, int[]... examples) {
    return Arrays.stream(examples)
            .mapToInt(ex -> ex[index]).sum() / examples.length;

}
```

You can try with :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] example1 = {85, 80, 85};
    int[] example2 = {75, 91, 52};
    int[] example3 = {92, 89, 78};
    // for row 1 (index 0)
    int average_row_1 = getRowAverage(0, example1, example2, example3);
    System.out.println(average_row_1);
}
```

Comment: You can make it even shorter by leveraging the lambda inside mapToInt: `Arrays.stream(examples).mapToInt(arr -> arr[index]).sum() / examples.length;`

Comment: @PaulLemarchand thank you and it seems like a nice answer and as a novice in Java, this seems like a bit advanced for me.